# Tkinter partially click through-able? (Windows only)

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, pyinstaller, transparent

I am writing an application that hovers a ruler over all other on-screen content.  I have made the tkinter window and associated canvas transparent using:

```
root.overrideredirect(True) #This hides the window outline/controls 
root.state('zoomed') #This scales the window to fill the page
root.configure(background=bgColor) #Set bg color of window (used to make transparent \/)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", bgColor) #Necessary for transparent, window
root.lift()#Lifting window above all others
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)#Hold window on top of all other windows
```

I am able to click through this application where transparent before compiling with pyinstaller to an exe.  However after compiling to an exe this is no longer possible.

I attempted the solution shared here: [Tkinter see through window not affected by mouse clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458775/tkinter-see-through-window-not-affected-by-mouse-clicks/29854420#29854420)
However this makes the entire window click through-able, meaning that I can no longer interact with the non-transparent portions of the top window (which I have to be able to do).

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Digital Ruler") # Getting window handle
# hwnd = root.winfo_id() getting hwnd with Tkinter windows
# hwnd = root.GetHandle() getting hwnd with wx windows
lExStyle = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
lExStyle |=  win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED 
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE , lExStyle )
```

I need to be able to move/interact with any colored sections of the root window but need to be able to click through any transparent sections... So far I have only been able to completely seize the mouse or completely miss it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have met this problem...

after a lot try, I found that if distribute the exe file with the manifest file which also generated by pyinstaller, the click through feature will work as expected.

Comment: Wow, this solved a problem I've had for a long time. Nice!