# Click-through tkinter windows

Tags: python, tkinter, window, transparent, click-through

The function is copied from [Tying to set non-interactable (click-through) overlay with TkInter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114145/tying-to-set-non-interactableclick-through-overlay-with-tkinter)

Not only is the window not click through, the png is also not transparent.
PNG is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tlLl2hjPq38mc_c_PpMhkKDlP1HqvDY5/view

This is what the window looks like:

[image: screenshot of window]

What am I missing?

```
from tkinter import*
import win32gui

from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow, ShowWindow, FindWindow, SetWindowLong, GetWindowLong, SetLayeredWindowAttributes
from win32con import SW_MINIMIZE, WS_EX_LAYERED, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, GWL_EXSTYLE

def setClickthrough(hwnd):
   try:
       styles = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
       styles |= WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
       SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, styles)
       SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
   except Exception as e:
       print(e)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")


root.overrideredirect(1)

root.attributes('-topmost', 1)
pic = PhotoImage(file=r'on2.png')
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", 'white')

boardbutton = Label(root, image=pic, bd=0,
                    bg='white')
boardbutton.pack()
setClickthrough(root.winfo_id())
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have took the code of the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114145/tying-to-set-non-interactable-click-through-overlay-with-tkinter) and made it work. See code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import win32gui
import win32con

def setClickthrough(hwnd):
    print("setting window properties")
    try:
        styles = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
        styles = win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, styles)
        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# Dimensions
width = 1920 #self.winfo_screenwidth()
height = 1080 #self.winfo_screenheight()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (width, height))
root.title("Applepie")
root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'white', '-topmost', 1)
root.config(bg='white') 
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.25)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
bg = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg='white')

setClickthrough(bg.winfo_id())

frame = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="example.png")
bg.create_image(1920/2, 1080/2, image=frame)
bg.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The important difference between your try and the working example seems to be that there was in use the `hwnd` of a canvas instead of a window.

---

I'm not abel to do exactly what you wish for but I have provided some code that outputs me this and hopefully sadisfy your needs. The extra code just removes the decoration (`overrideredirect(1)`) and resizes the window to the img size, also it places it in the middle of the screen.:

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import win32gui
import win32con

def setClickthrough(hwnd):
    print("setting window properties")
    try:
        styles = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
        styles = win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, styles)
        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def size_position_for_picture():
    bbox = bg.bbox(img_id)
    w,h = bbox[2]-bbox[0],bbox[3]-bbox[1]
    x,y = sw/2-w/2,sh/2-h/2
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h, x,y))
    bg.configure(width=w,height=h)
    

root = Tk()

sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.overrideredirect(1)
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.75)
root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'white', '-topmost', 1)
bg = Canvas(root,bg='white',highlightthickness=0)
root.config(bg='white')

setClickthrough(bg.winfo_id())

frame = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="example.png")
img_id = bg.create_image(0,0, image=frame,anchor='nw')
bg.pack()

size_position_for_picture()
setClickthrough(bg.winfo_id())


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked for me, but now even when setting "-transparentcolor" to the background of a transparent image, it's not transparent

Answer (score 3):

I have a function doing this for an application of mine as well, the code looks very similar to yours with some minor tweaks. You can try it out:

```py
def set_clickthrough(hwnd, root):
    # Get window style and perform a 'bitwise or' operation to make the style layered and transparent, achieving
    # the clickthrough property
    l_ex_style = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
    l_ex_style |= win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED
    win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, l_ex_style)

    # Set the window to be transparent and appear always on top
    win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(0, 0, 0), 190, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)  # transparent
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y(), 0, 0, 0)
```

And also, the following function to disable the clickthrough again

```py
def disable_clickthrough(hwnd, root):
    # Calling the function again sets the extended style of the window to zero, reverting to a standard window
    win32api.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, 0)
    # Remove the always on top property again, in case always on top was set to false in options
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y(), 0, 0, 0)
```

You can get the window handle (`hwnd`) by calling `win32gui.FindWindow(None, root.title())`.

Comment: Window was not showing, it was due to "SetWindowsPos" having "cx=0" and "cy=0". Those parameters want width and height of the Window. So I changed "SetWindowPos" from `win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y(), 0, 0, 0)` to `win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y(), root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height(), 0)`.