# Tkinter: Cursor Active on Window Beneath Tkinter Only

Tags: image, tkinter, window, cursor, overlay

Im creating an Full Screen Overlay.
If you google "Twitch Overlay", you will understand what It will look like.

[image]

Whenever my Mouse is on top of the `tkinter` Image.
I am unable to click the Window Underneath it.

```py
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry('')
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.config(bg="blue")
root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "blue",'-topmost','true')
#root.lift()
#root.wm_attributes('-disabled',True)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="blue")
canvas.configure(width = 1280, height = 720)
canvas.grid()

tk_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="1.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tk_img, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

I've attempted to use `cursor='none'`, which does make the cursor invisible when I mouseover the image.
But the window below is not clickable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click-through tkinter windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544105/click-through-tkinter-windows)

Comment: It does make the screen below clickable, but it removes the Transparency from the image, putting a layer of transparent white over everything.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

def set_clickthrough(hwnd, root):
    # Get window style and perform a 'bitwise or' operation to make the style layered and transparent, achieving
    # the clickthrough property
    l_ex_style = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
    l_ex_style |= win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED
    win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, l_ex_style)

    # Set the window to be transparent and appear always on top
    win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(0, 0, 0), 100, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)  # transparent
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y(), root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height(), 0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "white",'-topmost',1)
root.config(bg="white")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg = 'white')
canvas.configure(width = 1280, height = 720)
canvas.grid()
set_clickthrough(canvas.winfo_id(),root)

tk_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="1.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tk_img, anchor="nw")
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Ive achieved the goal of making the screen below clickable, but it puts a layer of transparent white over everything.