# Win32Gui + Tkinter(Clickthrough Overlay, Transparent Background)

Tags: python, tkinter, overlay, transparent, win32gui

I am creating a Full Screen Desktop Overlay.
On the Overlay, I am placing a PNG Image with Transparency.
The Image should be 100% visible, but the Background should be completely Transparent.
I should be able to clickthrough the Image, and the Transparent areas of the Image/Full screen Overlay.

I have successfully completed both tasks with slightly varying Code.
But I am unable to combine the Tasks.

Here is the Original Question containing both sets of Code, and the Effects obtained.

Thank You for your time!!
[Tkinter: Cursor Active on Window Beneath Tkinter Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506047/tkinter-cursor-active-on-window-beneath-tkinter-only/77508705#77508705)

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
import tkinter as tk

def set_clickthrough(hwnd, root):
    # Get window style and perform a 'bitwise or' operation to make the style layered and transparent, achieving
    # the clickthrough property
    l_ex_style = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
    l_ex_style |= win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED
    win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, l_ex_style)

    # Set the window to be transparent and appear always on top
    win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(0, 0, 0), 100, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)  # transparent
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y(), root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height(), 0)
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "white",'-topmost',1)
root.config(bg="white")





canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg = 'white')
canvas.configure(width = 1280, height = 720)
canvas.grid()
set_clickthrough(canvas.winfo_id(),root)


tk_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="1.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tk_img, anchor="nw")
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see a `mainloop` call.

Comment: Added the Mainloop

Comment: It worked for me. No issue problem so far.