# win32gui.SetWindowLong sometimes gets stuck in the middle of execution

Tags: python

I use this code(https://stackoverflow.com/a/67545792/22334744) to allow background widgets in the tkinter window to pass through clicks, but sometimes the program freezes in the middle of the execution of win32gui.SetWindowLong in that code. Adding time.sleep to delay the execution of that code slightly reduces the frequency of the error, but it still happens. No error codes were output.

```
def setClickthrough(hwnd):
    print("setting window properties")
    try:
        styles = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
        styles = win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        time.sleep(0.3)
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, styles)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```