# Make mouse ignore lines drawn by tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Background:

I have created a python script for a simple static crosshair, that displays always on the screen.
When the script runs, i can use my pc like the crosshair is not there except when touching the lines of the crosshair.
I want it to not interrupt with the user activity.
Can I achieve this with python?

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from win32gui import SetWindowLong, GetWindowLong, SetLayeredWindowAttributes
from win32con import WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, GWL_EXSTYLE, LWA_ALPHA

def setClickthrough(hwnd):
    print("setting window properties")
    try:
        styles = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
        styles = WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, styles)
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# Define crosshair parameters
crosshair_color = 'red'
crosshair_size = 30
crosshair_thickness = 10

# Create a transparent window
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.attributes("-transparent", "white", '-topmost', 1)

# Get the screen dimensions
screen_width, screen_height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()

root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}+0+0")

# Create a canvas on the window to draw the crosshair
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white', highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Draw horizontal line
canvas.create_line(screen_width // 2 - crosshair_size, screen_height // 2, screen_width // 2 + crosshair_size, screen_height // 2,
                fill=crosshair_color, width=crosshair_thickness)

# Draw vertical line
canvas.create_line(screen_width // 2, screen_height // 2 - crosshair_size, screen_width // 2, screen_height // 2 + crosshair_size,
                fill=crosshair_color, width=crosshair_thickness)
        
setClickthrough(canvas.winfo_id())

root.attributes("-topmost", True)
root.update_idletasks()

# Function to exit the script when you press a key (e.g., ESC)
def exit_script(event):
    root.destroy()

root.bind("<Escape>", exit_script)

# Start the Tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()
```

The problem:
The actual problem is for example if I'm on a website and I want to select some text that is right under the crosshair, I can't reach it. I want somehow to make the mouse ignore all gui.

Here is a video of the problem, look at the mouse changes and the highlight color change when hovering or clicking the crosshair.
(Sorry for the bad quality, the screen recorder didn't capture the crosshair)
[crosshair interact with mouse example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXndz.gif)

I tried looking online and with ai assistances which haven't got me anywhere.
Didn't crossed with a problem like this.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: FWIW: Unless you're using `pyautogui` elsewhere, you don't need it here. You can get the screen dimensions from `root.winfo_screenwidth()` and `root.winfo_screenheight` Also, there's an unassigned expression `screen_height // 2` that isn't doing anything - I'm guessing it should have been part of the comment above it.

Comment: @acw1668 I think the issue is that the crosshair itself is still interactable (the cursor changes, anyway...), if I understand correctly

Comment: Yes, I had problem pasting to code, you can see I ucidently comment out some line, will be fixed here. I just can't make the lines interactive disabled

Comment: Also: is your intention to have the crosshair at the center of the screen? Because that's not where it appears for me.

Comment: Yes, for me it does, may be because I didn't considered dimensions issues yet.

Comment: The actual problem is for example if I's on a website and I want to select some text that is right under the crosshair, I can't reach it.
I want somehow to make the mouse ignore all gui.

Comment: Can this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114145/tying-to-set-non-interactable-click-through-overlay-with-tkinter or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544105/click-through-tkinter-windows

Comment: Full disclosure: I don't have `pyautogui` installed, so the pure tkinter implementation may need some tweaking

Comment: I removed the pyautogui as you suggested.
I tried the answer from the link you gave me as you can see in the edited code, but still not help.
I also added a gif that shows the problem.

Comment: tkinter might not even be able to do this at all; it could be that a more low-level library is needed, like `PyGetWindow`, `pywin32` or even `ctypes`. Otherwise there might not be enough control in Tkinter. You specifically need to set the window style of `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT `, which "makes your events (like mouse clicks) fall through your window, amongst other things".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try implement this kind of libraries and will post if there will be any success.
If anyone see this and know the solution please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Its kind of a cheaty solution but basically I made two different canvases, one for vertical and one for horizontal, with that I could use the click through and don't mind the background because the canvases are made with the of the rectangle sizes.
Its not good for custom crosshairs images, but for the simple one it does the job.

[crosshair example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuZBi.png)
[crosshair example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNyf7.png)
[crosshair example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzFtL.png)

Code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, CENTER
from win32gui import GetWindowLong, SetWindowLong, SetLayeredWindowAttributes
from win32con import GWL_EXSTYLE, LWA_ALPHA, WS_EX_LAYERED

def setClickthrough(hwnd):
    print("setting window properties")
    try:
        styles = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
        styles = WS_EX_LAYERED
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, styles)
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


root = Tk()

# Controll thickness and length
crosshair_thickness = 5
crosshair_length = 600

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.overrideredirect(1)
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'black', '-topmost', 1)
horizontal = Canvas(root, bg="black", highlightthickness=0, width=crosshair_length, height=crosshair_thickness)
vertical = Canvas(root, bg="black", highlightthickness=0, width=crosshair_thickness, height=crosshair_length)
root.config(bg='black')

setClickthrough(horizontal.winfo_id())
setClickthrough(vertical.winfo_id())


img_H = horizontal.create_rectangle(-1, -1, crosshair_length, crosshair_thickness, fill='red')
img_V = vertical.create_rectangle(-1, -1, crosshair_thickness, crosshair_length, fill='red')
horizontal.pack()
vertical.pack()

root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (screen_width,screen_height, 0, 0))
horizontal.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
vertical.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```