# python - Wx see through window user input data collection

Tags: python, wxpython, overlay, wxwidgets

I am creating a multi touch accuracy checking device that indicates where the user should touch the screen. It overlays a semi transparent image over an exe called using subprocess with wx as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458775/tkinter-see-through-window-not-affected-by-mouse-clicks/29854420#29854420).

I want to output to terminal to prompt user for each data collection point but I can't exit MainLoop() to prompt the user, collect data, and repeat. Press and unpress of tab records one instance of touch in the exe.

Thank you

```
def scale_bitmap(bitmap, width, height):
    image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)
    image = image.Scale(width, height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
    result = wx.Bitmap(image)
    return result

for x in range(1, 7):
    app = wx.App()
    trans = 100

    frame1 = wx.Frame(None, -1, "KEA", style=wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
    # create the class instance
    frame1.ShowFullScreen(True)
    image_file = "6dataPoints.jpg"
    bmp1 = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    bmp1 = scale_bitmap(bmp1, GetSystemMetrics(1) * 1.5, GetSystemMetrics(1))
    bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(frame1, -1, bmp1, (-100, 0))
    hwnd = frame1.GetHandle()

    extendedStyleSettings = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
    win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE,
                           extendedStyleSettings | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT)
    win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)

    frame1.SetTransparent(trans)

    print("Place fingers over data collection point %d" % (x))
    pyautogui.keyDown("tab")
    pyautogui.keyUp("tab")

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `tkinter` when you're using wxwidgets?

Comment: Not sure but I guess what you are looking for is: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.AppConsole.html

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use the terminal for output and prompts instead of doing it in the GUI? It would make sense to just show some (modal) dialog in the GUI instead.

If you really want to use both (blocking) terminal IO and GUI from the same program, the simplest way is to do it from two different threads, with one thread reserved for the GUI stuff only.