# how could I make click events pass through a window using python?

Tags: python, window

I want to add overlays to my screen that displays some shapes using python and I am trying to achieve this by making a window transparent and make click events pass through the window. I am using python 3.6 (i can change the version if neccesary) and I am on windows 10.

**Note:** similar questions have been asked in the past [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546104/how-to-make-click-events-pass-though-a-tkinter-window) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458775/tkinter-see-through-window-not-affected-by-mouse-clicks/29854420#29854420) but neither answer my question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can have a `canvas` then configure as `window` adjust `bindtags` to sub-canvas. Then  add a callback for button click events on the inner canvas.

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am using pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter does not have passing events to parent widgets. But it is possible to simulate the effect through the use of  `bindtags`

Making a binding to a widget is not equal to adding a binding to a widget. It is binding to a `bindtag` which has the same name as the widget, but it's not actually the widget.

Widgets have a list of `bindtags`,  when an event happens on a widget, the bindings for each tag are processed.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class BuildCanvas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.main = tk.Canvas(self, width=250, height=250, 
                              borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                              background="linen")
        self.main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.main.bind("<1>", self.on_main_click)

        for x in range(10):
            for y in range(10):
                canvas = tk.Canvas(self.main, width=35, height=35, 
                                   borderwidth=1, highlightthickness=0,
                                   relief="groove")
                if ((x+y)%2 == 0):
                    canvas.configure(bg="yellow")

                self.main.create_window(x*45, y*45, anchor="nw", window=canvas)

                bindtags = list(canvas.bindtags())
                bindtags.insert(1, self.main)
                canvas.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
                canvas.bind("<1>", self.on_sub_click)


    def on_sub_click(self, event):
        print("sub-canvas binding")
        if event.widget.cget("background") == "yellow":
            return "break"

    def on_main_click(self, event):
        print("main widget binding")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    BuildCanvas(root).pack (fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```